# How to increment numbers by five in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

Hi so I am using C code and trying to create a table where the number gets incremented in multiples of 5 starting from 1 to 5 to 10 to... all the way until the user's input. What I've gotten so far is that it starts at 1 and then increases the number by 5 like 1 to 6 to 11 to 16... until it gets to where it can't increase the number by 5 anymore without going above the user's input. Could someone help me set up the for loop better?

Here's the segment of my code I'm talking about:

```
else //run this statement if the user inputs a number greater than 14
    {
        printf("Number   Approximation1         Approximation2\n-----------------------------------------------------\n"); //prints the header for second table

        for ( i = 1; i <= n; i += 5 )
        {
            printf("%d        %e            %e\n", i, stirling1( i ), stirling2( i )); //calls functions to input approximate factorials
        }
    }
```

So with this code if I input n as 28, I get i to increment from 1 to 6 to 11 to 16 to 21 to 26.

What I want the code to do if I input n as 28 is increment i from 1 to 5 to 10 to 15 to 20 to 25 to 28.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you want to increment by 4, 5, 5, 5, 5?  Or you want to round up to the next multiple of 5 after you've processed 1?

Comment: looks like you have special "one-off" conditions before and after the repetitiveness. I'd handle the first and last case specially and put the rest that's in between in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{
    printf("Number   Approximation1         Approximation2\n-----------------------------------------------------\n"); //prints the header for second table

    printf("%d        %e            %e\n", i, stirling1( 1 ), stirling2( 1 ));

    for ( i = 5; i <= n; i += 5 )
    {
        printf("%d        %e            %e\n", i, stirling1( i ), stirling2( i )); //calls functions to input approximate factorials
    }
}
```

This will print values for 1, 5, 10, 15, 20... and so on

Note that, besides an extra line of code, its faster than adding an "if" inside the loop.

Comment: i should begin at 0.

Comment: In the question, he wants to start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

I added two `if` statements which would help you deal with the special cases of having statements printed at i = 1 and i = n besides having the statement printed every 5.

```
else //run this statement if the user inputs a number greater than 14
{
    printf("Number   Approximation1         Approximation2\n-----------------------------------------------------\n"); //prints the header for second table

    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i += 5 )
    {
        printf("%d        %e            %e\n", i, stirling1( i ), stirling2( i )); //calls functions to input approximate factorials

        if (i == 1){
            //when it iterates at the end of this loop, i = 5. 
            //In your example, you will get i from 1 to 5 to 10 up to 25 etc.
            i = 0; 
        }

        if ( (i + 5) > n){
            // for the next loop, it will check if i will exceed n on the next increment. 
            // you do not want this to happen without printing for n = i. 
            //In your case if n = 28, then i will be set to 23, which will then increment to 28. 
            i = n - 5; 
        }
    }
}
```

There are probably other more elegant ways of achieving this, but this is just a simple example of what you could try.